# Преймущества двойного указателя перед одним указателем в реализации класса matrix

Tags: c++, оптимизация, проектирование

Есть 2 реализации класса `matrix` на С++. **Первый вариант** с использованием указателя на массив элементов матрицы `int *elems_`. Для получения элемента матрицы в классе перегружен оператор `()`:

```
int& operator() (size_t n, size_t m) const {
    return this->elems[m * this->cols + n];
}
```

**Второй вариант** с использованием двойного указателя (двумерный массив). Выглядит это так `int **elems_`. Для получения элемента матрицы такая перегрузка оператора:

```
int& operator() (size_t n, size_t m) const {
    return this->elems[m][n];
}
```

Какие есть плюсы и минусы при обоих подходах?

Comment: Скажу честно - всегда считал первый способ более простым и быстрым. Но когда писал как-то класс матрицы для своих целей, оставил возможность выбора представления. И - самому не верится, но второй вариант оказался в целом быстрее...

Comment: @Harry я так понимаю второй вариант быстрее за счет того что в первом случае часто используется умножение.

Comment: Я надеялся на то, что это скомпенсирует лучшая локальность, размещение в кэше, и отсутствие лишнего разыменования.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

На мой взгляд, здесь самый существенный момент - работа с большими матрицами. Ибо в таком случае большое значение имеет работа процессорного кэша. И тогда есть 2 аспекта:

1. Как реализован сам класс. С этой точки зрения, первый способ лучше, так как он выделяет один непрерывный блок данных, а второй - множество блоков поменьше (и они не обязаны быть смежными).
2. Как вы используете матрицу. Например, если вы последовательно обходите элементы матрицы построчно, то кэш используется эффективно. А если вы обращаетесь к случайным элементам матрицы, то будут частые промахи кэша, подкачка страниц, и все такое прочее. И тогда аспект 1 не имеет значения.

Кстати, совместить ваши способы можно таким образом:

- Выделить память одним большим куском;
- Создать также массив, который будет содержать указатели на начала строк матрицы;

Тогда доступ к элементу можно будет делать как в способе 2, а данные при этом будут лежать в непрерывном блоке данных как в способе 1. При этом накладные расходы - дополнительный массив для указателей (что и так имеется в способе 2).